# Can Foxx call a query defined in ArangoDb?

Tags: aql, foxx

I can't find out if it's possible to invoke AQL queries set up on the ArangoDb web UI in Foxx script - rather like stored procedures can be called by services of a RDMS.

So far all examples I've seen show the AQL embedded into the Foxx services JavaScript.

```
const result = db._query([name of query defined in Db], {
  "@arg": arg-value
}).toArray();
```

I would expect the query defined on the ArangoDb to run and pass argument value from Foxx service. but the _query method seems to only accept a query string.

Answer (score 0):

The queries are stored as properties of the user and as such are available via the `users`-API:

```
var _ = require("lodash"); // helper to group the queries
var users = require('@arangodb/users'); 
var myQueries = _.groupBy(users.document(users.currentUser())['extra']['queries'], 'name');

const result = db._query(myQueries['name of query defined in Db'], ...);
```

lodash is available per default, no need to install it.

This is not clearly documented anywhere -- I took a look at the network traffic of the query-editor, to find the queries under 'extra/queries' of the user; than I searched for a js user-API and found an article on 'User Managment'.  I'd say the lack of documentation is a clear 'caveat emptor' -- it might change without notice; but this should get you going.

Additionally, thinking a bit, I only tested this in `arangosh`, not a foxx app -- maybe the users module isn't available there.  If it works you will probably have to replace the `users.currentUser()` call with the username as string.

Given the ease this approach lends to breaking your application, I wouldn't recommend to use this (if it works...) outside of R&D and/or prototyping.

**Edit**: I implemented this to test it:

```js
router.post(
    '/getQueries',
    /**
     * @param {Object} req
     * @param {Object} res
     */
    function(req, res) {
        var _ = require("lodash"); // helper to group the queries
        var users = require('@arangodb/users'); 
        var myQueries = _.groupBy(users.document(req.body.user, ['extra']['queries'], 'name'));

        res.json({success: (myQueries !== null), queries: myQueries, error: null});
    }).summary('Return queries stored for the given user').body(joi.object().keys({
        'user': joi.string().required()
    }).unknown(true), ['json']);
```

This works, the queries are objects with of the following form:

```
[
               "value" => """
                 FOR x IN @params\n
                    RETURN x
                 """,
               "parameter" => [
                 "params" => "",
               ],
               "name" => "x_test",
             ],
```

so a foxx service can indeed access and execute queries stored for a user, but I still strongly suggest to not do this in production.